# laravel - add /public/ to routes

Tags: apache, laravel

I've moved my application and now I need to add /public/ before everything for it to work correctly. What setting do I need to change so that this happens automatically and css etc are loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

### Please, do not expose all your Laravel folders. This is a security risk

Instead of adding `/public/` after your domain, you should reconfigure your domain to redirect to `your/path/to/laravel/public/`. Otherwise, all other folders on the same level as public are accessible, which poses a **huge security risk**, because your .env file would be accessible too.

Comment: how do I do that? the site is only working when I add /public

Comment: You can configure your domain/apache so that the directory is not `path/to/laravel/` but `path/to/laravel/public` instead! How you do that depends on your host or server!

Answer (score 0):

Change in .env

```
APP_URL=http://somedomain.com/public/
```

instead of

```
APP_URL=http://somedomain.com/
```

And for baseurl you can use

```
config('app.url)
```

It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it easy by just redirect the domain path to public folder. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For laravel 5:

1. Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php
2. copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder.
3. Changing .htaccess it a bit as follows for statics:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
> RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
> ```

If there are any other static files needed just add the extension to the previous declared list